# how to align column names in Postgres Spring-data and liquibase?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, liquibase

I was trying to follow [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/integrating-spring-data-jpa-postgresql-liquibase/) to set up a simple spring boot app with postgres. They used Docker to set up the db, and liquibase. I have used spring-data and JPA before but not postgres or liquibase.

I was trying to set up a simple Student db. Here's my entity:

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

Here's the changelog for liquibase

```
create table "student" (
    id bigserial not null,
    firstName varchar(50) not null,
    lastName varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

I am loading a few students via a class implementing CommandLineRunner, just to have some initial data

Upon startup, I get the following error:

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "first_name" of relation "student" does not exist

What is changing the column of firstName into first_name? 
I could use @Column("first_name") in the Student entity but then that doesn't seem to line up with the table definition in the changeset.

I don't know why liquibase needs the table definition, with JPA there. I thought it was easier without it, by just letting JPA create the table from the @Entity.

Bigger picture is I'm just trying to do a proof of concept/scaffold for a quick spring boot app with postgres on the backend and ReactJS on the front end. [This tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/#react-and-spring-data-rest-part-2) might be better for that, if I could get the postgres back end figured out. Don't really need docker, but I thought that would make it easier. But now that and liquibase seem to be creating a problem by persisting a db and table that don't match up.

Comment: are you sure that your table is not created with hibernate and is really created with liquibase?

Comment: I have no idea; how would I tell that? and why might hibernate be creating that column with first_name?

Comment: try to define spring's property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` this will prevent creating your database by hibernate. If you want to know why your columns are named as they are try to search for hibernate naming strategy.